# Mac OS X Firewall isn't firewalling

Tags: firewall, mac-osx-server, pf, ipfw

Rather confused by the results I'm getting on a Mac OS X Server running 10.8. I have an app that is running a web server on port 8000, which I want to be visible only to localhost. This seems perfectly suited for the GUI OS X firewall, but after turning it on (and searching its limited options), I'm still able to connect to port 8000 from remote computers.

After turning the firewall on, I automatically have ports open for AFP, SSH, Remote Management, and Screen Sharing, none of which should affect 8000 AFAIK. What am I missing here? And is this a job for the built-in firewall, or should I be looking at pf or ipfw?

Answer (score 0):

Open `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall`,
switch to superuser by unlocking it,
select `Firewall Options...`,

click on the <kbd>+</kbd>, select your application server, and click on the <kbd>Add</kbd> button to create a new firewall entry for your server.

For this new entry select on the right `Block incoming connections`.

Check your server locally and remotely.